# How to share NgxPermissionsService instances across AppModule, Feature Module and a Library Module

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-dependency-injection

I'm trying to use `ngx-permissions` to manage my app permissions.

My app is depending on a library to share some features to different apps and the permissions will be loaded by this library.

the problem here is, the library has a different instance than the main app. so the permissions are not available for the app to use.

Can anybody help me on this please?

i tried to import `NgxPermissionsModule` to the libaray with `forRoot()`, with `forChild()` and without both also. nothing helps sharing the injection from app to library